# React Native - Dangerous permissions auto granted without pop-up

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

I am new to react-native and trying out permission model. I added following entry in AndroidManifes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Added following function

```
async requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      {
        'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera")
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
```

And registered it in constructor as follows

```
this.requestCameraPermission = this.requestCameraPermission.bind(this);
```

And called it as

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.requestCameraPermission();
  }
```

I am getting permission auto granted without any pop-up to user. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or expecting wrong.

Comment: what is the os version? Runtime permission model works for android M and above. Below android M you will get all permissions by default.

Comment: from my recollection, the Android permissions are requested at install time based on the manifest.  But that's just what I've been told by some Android devs; I don't have any personal experience

Comment: @ankitAggarwal I am running it on android 7.0 device.

Comment: @GarrettMcCullough Android permission are requested at install time on devices below Android M. We need to explicitly ask for dangerous permissions at runtime from Android M onwards.

Comment: @Virat18 you are right. It is auto granting whatever permission I am adding in the manifest. Also, there are few extra permissions which are not mentioned in the manifest and still granted like PHONE_STATE and EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Will try to check the source code.